# Method in ICollection in C# that adds all elements of another ICollection to it

Tags: c#, collections

Is there some method in ICollection in C# that would add all elements of another collection?
Right now I have to always write foreach cycle for this:

```
ICollection<Letter> allLetters = ... //some initalization
ICollection<Letter> justWrittenLetters = ... //some initalization
... //some code, adding to elements to those ICollections

foreach(Letter newLetter in justWrittenLetters){
    allLetters.add(newLetter);
}
```

My question is, is there method that can replace that cycle? Like for example the method [`addAll(Collection c)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in Java ? So I would write only something like:

```
allLetters.addAll(justWrittenLetters);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There isn't a method like this for ICollection. You have two options, either use a different type such as List which has the AddRange() method or alternatively, create an extension method:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> newItems)
    {
        foreach (T item in newItems)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```